# calculate the ideal generated by $\langle2,x\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't get it how calculate $\langle2,x\rangle$. I need that because I want to use that these ideals cannot be generated by one single element. And concludes that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If $\langle 2,x \rangle=\langle p(x)\rangle$ then $p(x)|2 $ & $p(x)|x$ which is a contradiction

Comment: why is a contradiction?

Comment: $p(x)|2\Rightarrow p(x)=\pm1,\pm2$ can you continue?

Comment: but $p(x)|x$ means that there exist a $g(x)$ such that $p(x)*g(x) = x$ and we can set $g(x) = p(x)^{-1}*x$   becuase $p(x)$ is a constant also the reciprocal an then $g(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: maybe you have written something wrong, $p(x)|x$ means $x=p(x)g(x)$ so $\deg p(x)=1 \text{ or }0\Rightarrow p(x)=\pm1,\pm x$

Comment: Can you conclude that $p(x)=\pm1$?

Comment: it semms to me that $p(x) = ±1$ is a common solution.

Comment: right! Now we have $\langle 2,x\rangle=\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, is this a contradiction?

Comment: I don't know.. the thing is that I don't understand $<1>$ neither $<2,x>$ linear combination under the ring in discussion or what?

Comment: So $\langle1\rangle$ is the whole $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\langle2,x\rangle=\{2p(x)+xq(x):p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}$. Can $3\in\langle2,x \rangle$?

Comment: I see.. so it is something like the generators of vector spaces... thank you.

Comment: Yes, can you show that $3\not\in \langle2,x\rangle$ in order to reach a contradiction?

Comment: intuitively yes but not in a formal writing...

Comment: If $3=2a(x)+xb(x)$ for some $a(x),b(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then for $x=0$ we have $3=2a(0)$ so $2|3$ which is the contradiction

Comment: Pretty nice...now is clear.  I really appreciate it .